# Laravel 5 query `LIKE` issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `special_number` table with a prefix column. The column contains `022`,`021` etc data. I have a number `0216627363021`. How I match the column using `LIKE` keyword to get the row.

```
$rate = Special::where('user_id',$user_id)
            ->where(DB::raw("prefix LIKE $number"))
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("prefix LIKE SUBSTR($number,1,-1)"))
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("prefix LIKE SUBSTR($number,1,-2)"))
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("prefix LIKE SUBSTR($number,1,-3)"))
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("prefix LIKE SUBSTR($number,1,-4)"))
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("prefix LIKE SUBSTR($number,1,-5)"))
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("prefix LIKE SUBSTR($number,1,-6)"))
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("prefix LIKE SUBSTR($number,1,-7)"))
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("prefix LIKE SUBSTR($number,1,-8)"))
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("prefix LIKE SUBSTR($number,1,-9)"))
            ->orWhere(DB::raw("prefix LIKE SUBSTR($number,1,-10)"))
            ->first();
```

but it return NULL. Where is the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a part of the value just use wildcard with `like`:

```php
$rate = Special::where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->where('prefix', 'like', '%' . $number . '%')
        ->first();
```

This will match the string inside the prefix at any point. If you want to get results for the prefix value that starts with the number use:

```php
->where('prefix', 'like', $number . '%')
```

Or if you want to match prefix values that end with that number use:

```php
->where('prefix', 'like', '%' . $number)
```